# Parsing links from html with gawk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, gawk

I'm trying to take googles html, and parse out the links. I use curl obtain the html then pass it to gawk. From gawk I used the match() function, and it works but it only returns a small amount of links. Maybe 10 at most. If I test my regex on regex101.com it returns 51 links using the `g` global modifier. How can I use this in gawk to obtain all the links (relative and absolute)?

```
#!/bin/bash

html=$(curl -L "http://google.com")

echo "${html}" | gawk '
  BEGIN {
    RS=" "
    IGNORECASE=1
  }
  {
    match($0, /href=\"([^\"]*)/, array);
    if (length(array[1]) > 0) {
      print array[1];
    }
  }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of awk you can also use `grep -oP`:

```
curl -sL "http://google.com" | grep -iPo 'href="\K[^"]+'
```

However this is also fetching 31 links for me. This may vary with your browser because `google.com` serves a different page for different locations/signed in users.

Comment: thanks but I get `usage: grep` as the output and it doesn't run?

Comment: Hmm you must be using older grep. `grep -P` requires newer gnu grep

Comment: i have grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: Hmm that's not gnu grep. On OSX I used `home brew` to get gnu grep.

Comment: Also, quite possibly, google could use ajax to add some more links to page after the page loads. I would suggest that for testing, OP should use curl just once to download the page to a file on the disk. Then use the same html page contents with awk, grep, regex101.com, to see if OP gets same results every time.

Answer (score 1):

Match only matches the leftmost match, you need to update the line each time.

Try

```
 curl -sL "http://google.com" | gawk '{while(match($0, /href=\"([^\"]+)/, array)){
      $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);print array[1]}}'
```